# Получить график частот из wav-файла

Tags: python, аудио, wav

Как можно изменить код, чтобы выводилась не амплитуда, а частота wav-файла?

```
from os.path import dirname, join as pjoin
from scipy.io import wavfile
import scipy.io

data_dir = pjoin(dirname(scipy.io.__file__), 'tests', 'data')
wav_fname = pjoin(data_dir, 'test-8000Hz-le-2ch-1byteu.wav')

samplerate, data = wavfile.read(wav_fname)
print(f"number of channels = {data.shape[1]}")

length = data.shape[0] / samplerate
print(f"length = {length}s")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
time = np.linspace(0., length, data.shape[0])
plt.plot(time, data[:, 0], label="Left channel")
plt.plot(time, data[:, 1], label="Right channel")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Хаха. Приведу аналог вопроса из немного другой сферы: "у меня есть код, который считает таблицу умножения. Как его переделать, чтобы он решал дифференциальные уравнения". Надеюсь, аналогия, ясна. Никак. Нужно или изучить матчасть и написать самому (ключевое слово - FFT), или, поискать и, если повезет, найти модуль, который, может быть, уже написал кто-то другой.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html